# Need to generate one WSDL file from many .java files using maven

Tags: java, maven, wsdl

I'm stuck with generating a WSDL file from a java application where i have many .java files. I'm  able to generate one WSDL from from one java class file, but I need to generate only one  WSDL file for the java application. We are using Weblogic as our deployment server. 
Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It may help if you clarify: What plugin/tool are you using to generate the wsdl, a couple of example classes and the resulting wsdl. The exact input to your generation tool will also be helpful

Comment: also when you mean many java files, do you mean many webservices within the same application?

Comment: for my application i need to generate only one webservices.xml file, but in order to generate this first we need to generate a WSDL file if iam not wrong. so now i got struck up to generate the wsdl file for my application. So can anyone please explaing me how to write the pom to generate a wsdl when i have many .java files in the application.

Comment: <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
 <version>2.6.3</version>
 <dependencies> <dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
 <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
<artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
</dependency>

Comment: </dependencies>
<executions>
<execution>
<id>process-classes</id>
<phase>process-sources</phase>
<configuration>
<className>com.Mycompany.name.work</className>
<outputFile>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/wsdl/work.wsdl</outputFile>
<genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
</configuration>
<goals> <goal>java2ws</goal></goals>
</execution></executions></plugin>

Comment: This is my pom with which i can generate one wsdl for one .java file, but i need to generate only one wsdl file for my entire application, so how can i write the pom for that.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. If you look at the [documentation of the Java2WS plugin](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/java-to-ws.html) it becomes clear that they only support generating 1 WSDL from 1 Java file:

> java2ws - uses a Web service endpoint's implementation (SEI) class and
>   associated types classes to generate a WSDL file